# How to set location coordinates for maptoolbar's navigation icon?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Map in my app and I'm enabling the map toolbar using this line: `mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);`.

So, this shows 2 icons on the bottom-right corner of the map, one of which is the 'navigation' icon (left icon below).

[image]

**What I want** is to know that how can I set the location coordinates **from where to where** (start and end location coordinates) the navigation would be shown on clicking this navigation icon?

Is there any way?

Please let me know,

Comment: It consider `start location = your current location` and `end location = marker location` that you clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you click on any `Marker` available on the map, Once you click on the marker it automatically takes you to the GoogleMap App and shows you a route to the marker you clicked.

Comment: Oh! Does it navigate to the marker which has been clicked?

Comment: Yes. Plot a dummy marker on the map(Default is Sydney) and tap on the marker, u will see this tool comes out from right-end side, while pressing on navigation. It takes u to google-maps app and gives u route. try it. I'm using same on my app.

Comment: done. is there a way to show the the toolbar when map is first shown and when user clicks the navigation button, it navigates to a particular marker?

Comment: Nope, it calls on marker click. Alternate is to add a message to click on shown toolbox. The basic info of this is to provide navigation to a click area, via **Only GoogleMaps**. When a user or u mark a marker on map, u ckick on the marker and it will take u to navigation.